# How can I use nested structures in meteor spacebars?

Tags: javascript, html, css, meteor

In the following example I have registered an helper "currentUser" in a file utils.js in the lib folder of the client. I am trying to align the messages right or left if the condition satisfies.

```
<template name="chatMessages">
{{#each chatMessages}}
    {{#if currentUser {{email}}}}
        <b style="float:right;">{{message}}</b>
        <br>
    {{else}}
        <b style="float:left;">{{message}}</b>
        <br>
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

> The helper code is:

```
Template.registerHelper("currentUser", function(input) {
    return Session.get("userMail") === input;
});
```

Comment: What error are you seeing? Also, what is the type of the variable returned by your helper? Is it an object?

Comment: I was getting an error like Expected identifier, number, string, boolean, null, or a sub expression enclosed in "(", ")"
...   {{#if currentUser {{email}}}}, and the helper was returning an array of objects.But the answer below,solved the issue,Thank You :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't put the parameter to the helper inside curly braces, i.e. instead of:

```
  {{#if currentUser {{email}}}}
```

use

```
  {{#if currentUser email}}
```

Assuming that the variable `email` is defined in the data scope of the helper! (you don't show that part).